# Как перенести заказы, товары, карточки товаров и пользователей с dev на prod или наоборот?

Tags: drupal

Веду работу на копии сайта-магазина, база на нем естественно устарела в сравнении с production версией сайта.

Как проще всего перенести товары, карточки товаров, заказы, пользователей, профили пользователей с production на dev?

Легче всего было было просто перенести соответствующие таблицы БД, но наверняка у очевидных для переноса таблиц есть куча связей с неочевидными таблицами.

Еще вариант с помощью Feeds, но через него не получится перенести пользователей и заказы.

Если переносить наоборот с dev на рабочий сайт, то и Feautures насколько понимаю мало поможет. Нужно не только настройки перенести, но и часть содержимого: новые блоки, формы.

Уже склоняюсь к тому чтобы вручную создать все это на живом сайте, только большая проблема именно с тем что надо наживую все делать и не закосячить.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы чувствуете неуверенность в ваших действиях, думаю, надо делать так:

1. Сделать бекап dev базы
2. Попытаться перенести необходимые таблицы с изменениями из продакшен
3. Проверить, все ли работает верно, если нет - узнать почему, откатить бекап и пробовать снова.
4. Полученную базу вывести на продакшен